# Underscore/Lo-Dash _.each not returning array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I was initially trying to do this:

```
var array = ['A','B','C'];
array = _.each(array, function(item) { return item + '+' });
```

to get this:

```
['A+','B+','C+'];
```

but _.each does not seem to return a function.

I eventually settled on this:

```
var array = ['A','B','C'];
newArray = [];
_.each(array, function(item) {
  newArray.push(item + '+');
});
```

but it seems pretty clunky by comparison.

Am I using _.each incorrectly, or is there another function I should be using?

Comment: use _.map to return an array - _.each is just an iterator method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there another function I should be using?

Yes. `each` never returns an array, it just iterates. Use [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) to produce an array of callback results.

```
var array = _.map(['A','B','C'], function(item) { return item + '+' });
```

Answer (score 3):

Making my comment an answer instead - use _.map to return an array. The _.each method will simply iterate through your collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = _.map(array, function(item) {
  return item + '+';
});
```